# Can I pass a setter as an argument to another widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget (slider) that changes a value.

Right now, I am passing a VoidCallback to each slider, so they can update the individual setter of the provider.

Is it possible to pass the setter in the constructor of the slider, so it can call the setter directly, thus simplifying the construction of the slider (no VoidCallbacks needed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can by wrapping the setter in a function. So a callback is still needed but it's a lean wrapper around the setter. Not much boilerplate to handle here. I made an example on gist/dartpad:

https://dartpad.dev/?id=38f013e47f8c85057c44a0a326df33dd

```dart
void main() async {
  final a = A(value: 2);
  print('A=${a.value}');
  final setter = (int i) => a.data = i;
  final b = B(callback: setter);
  b.exec(10);
  print('A=${a.value}');
}

class A {
    int value;
    A({required this.value});
  
    set data(int newValue) => value = newValue;
}

class B {
  final void Function(int) callback;
  
  B({required this.callback});
  
  void exec(int i){
    callback(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! And I can use the wrapper B for all different setters of A, right?

Comment: you can wrap and pass has many setter as you want. it all comes down to how many parameter you want to pass or how complex you want your wrapper to be. If you approve my recommendation please select it at the valid answer ;-)

Comment: Setters can only have one parameter, so the example is perfect :) Will maybe use Object or <T> instead of int, so it's universal.

Comment: @Achim good idea making it generic will improve the design